# Reading a word document in PHP

Tags: php

I need a fairly reliable way of getting a word document into a string in PHP.

I've just installed Antiword. It works with many files, both doc and docx but it has trouble with certain documents and gives the error: **"[filename] is not a Word document"**, even though they are.

I read this in regards to this problem:

> This is the new-style XML-in-a-zip-container format, which is
>   completely different to the binary Microsoft Word formats which
>   antiword handles most of.
>
> There's no realistic likelihood of antiword supporting this - the last
>   antiword upstream release was 2005-10-21 (which predates this XML
>   format).

Is there some way of reading these new format Word documents in PHP?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord?

Comment: I did consider that but I'm dubious about it's capabilities after reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555057/how-to-read-doc-file-via-phpword

Comment: As of 2018, PHPWord is considered to be the 'best' PHP library for reading MS Word files, but: it grabs all the info from you file (style, etc.) and gives out a huge object of arrays and objects, where you have to find your text (properties where test is hidden are protected, so you will have to make them public inside the PHPWord library; good luck). And, after testing it on dozens of .doc files, I can now say that PHPWord can sometimes get only 50-60% of text, with no apparent explanation as to why. So, not the best solution, actually.

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/nickrouty/6f5ed07e79d2223b279fc5e662264b10) - this one seems to be a better solution IF you need TEXT ONLY. tested it for some 30 .doc files, text is extracted from the first to the last word.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), which is part of PHPOffice... I haven't used it, but i have used PHPExcel and it works flawelessly on the new format (xml in zip). 
Give it a try!!

Comment: Ok thanks, it's been suggested twice so I'll give it a go and report back